# Kibana, filter data on the basis of one field and then grouping values on basis of timestamp (yearly)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have three fields in my data: `tran_date`, `use_case`, `Amount`.

`use_case` field having multiple values i.e. *B2B*, *cash_in*, *C2C* etc.

I want to plot a bar chart by sum up `Amount` field against `use_case` (*B2B*, *cash_in* only) then want to group data on yearly basis . so there will be a bar for each year summing up the `Amount` against use case *B2B*, *cash_in*.

I explored filter and sub-buckets but they don't seem to provide grouping of values.

Answer (score 0):

"sub buckets" create aggregations, which are groupings.  Setup your x-axis as a Date Histogram on @timestamp, then add a sub-bucket using Terms for use_case.  To get the sum, edit the y-axis (metrics).